# Rails ORM for Cassandra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cassandra

this question may have been asked many times, but could not find any suitable answer. Is there any ORM on Rails3 for Cassandra.

I have searched google and found following.

- [fauna/cassandra](https://github.com/fauna/cassandra) - cassandra client for rails
- [carbonfive/active_column](https://github.com/carbonfive/active_column) - last updated 13-may-2011
- [winebarrel/activerecord-cassandra-adapter](https://bitbucket.org/winebarrel/activerecord-cassandra-adapter) - last updated 5 months ago
- [scrum8/cassandrb](https://github.com/scrum8/cassandrb) - last updated 01-mar-2011
- [NZKoz/cassandra_object](https://github.com/NZKoz/cassandra_object) - last updated 30-may-2010
- [astrails/smallrecord](https://github.com/astrails/smallrecord) - last updated 14-apr-2010
- [azati/ActiveCassandra](https://github.com/azati/ActiveCassandra) - last updated 03-jun-2010

Please help me out in deciding which one I should go with.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you can put anything not updated in 2011 on the "don't bother" list. 0.7 was released in January 2011 and has some API incompatiblities with earlier clients.

Of the ones left, fauna/cassandra is a lower-level client (I suspect most of the others use it as a starting point), which leaves a very short list left to evaluate. Based purely on commit activity I suspect active_column is your best bet.

For 0.8.1 (it won't be ready in time to ship with 0.8.0) we're working on a CQL driver that we hope will provide Rails compatibility out of the box.  That will be in the Cassandra source tree under drivers/ when it's ready.

Comment: Thanks jbellis. I also came to same conclusion that i should go with active_column, but there are some problems - like I am not able to use active_column with Devise. so there are 2 options - first would be to go with 2 databases (MySQL and cassandra) which I personally don't like to and second would be to change the authentication plugin from Devise to something else which supports cassandra. anyways thanks for the help

Comment: jbelis, How would you evaluate situation as for June 2012?

Answer (score 11):

#### Update: February 2013

- [data-axle/cassandra_object](https://github.com/data-axle/cassandra_object) aka `gotime-cassandra_object` gem
- [brewster/cequel](https://github.com/brewster/cequel) aka `cequel` gem
- [twitter/cassandra](https://github.com/twitter/cassandra) - a ruby client for Cassandra

and if you're using [Datastax](http://www.datastax.com):

- [jasonmk/datastax_rails](https://github.com/jasonmk/datastax_rails) - aka `datastax_rails` gem

Answer (score 7):

**Update: June 2014**

Building off of mccannf's suggestions, I can personally verify that [cequel](https://github.com/cequel/cequel) is a top-notch ORM that has an excellent, straightforward API that is ActiveRecord-like while being slightly more transparent (less behind-the-scenes magic than AR). It is currently being maintained as of June 2014.

Answer (score 4):

**Update: June 2013**

[hsgubert/cassandra_migrations](https://github.com/hsgubert/cassandra_migrations)

It gives access to Cassandra through CQL3 and integrates with rails to manage schema with migrations.