# Using Cassandra with rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cassandra

I would like to use cassandra with my rails application. There are few questions in my mind:
* How can I connection pool the cassandra clients?
* How can I store cassandra client object in a place that is shared among all my model objects during the duration of request. Of course if there is a connection pool, I need to return the object back to the pool at the end of request processing.

Thanks a lot
Behrang

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails ORM for Cassandra](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157760/rails-orm-for-cassandra)

Comment: How are you running your Rails app in production? Passenger, Unicorn, ...?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

I should use `Thread.current[]` to ensure the cassandra client is not recreated per request.

Something like:

```
Thread.current[:cassandra_client] ||= Cassandra.new(keyspace, servers)
```