# Rails gem for cassandra

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, cassandra

Is there any better ORM for Rails with Cassandra? I have looked a lot and found a lot of ORM's for cassandra which are not updated. So can any one help me determine which will be best for use with Cassandra and Rails 3.2?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157760/rails-orm-for-cassandra, although that hasn't been updated in a while.