# How to Migrate cassandra with ruby on rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, orm, cassandra

I'm working on a project that is considering using Ruby on Rails and Cassandra as a database.

I have referred some website `https://github.com/cequel/cequel/` to connect rails with Cassandra but some problem in finding cequel:configuration generator.

How do i migrate Cassandra data with ruby on rails?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update what is the error you are getting while using [cequel](https://github.com/cequel/cequel).

There are also various other options you can use,

- [datastax-rails](https://github.com/jasonmk/datastax_rails) (If you are using [Datastax](http://www.datastax.com/))
- [cql-rb](https://github.com/iconara/cql-rb)
- [Cassandra Migrations](https://github.com/hsgubert/cassandra_migrations)
- [Cassandra Object](https://github.com/data-axle/cassandra_object)

There is also a stackoverflow post  for [Rails ORM with Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157760/rails-orm-for-cassandra)

Comment: For generate a default configuration file i have used a command "rails g cequel:configuration" and i got an error-'could not find generator cequel:configuration'